# The property of maxWidth does not work for the Chinese words

Tags: word-wrap, drawtext, jcanvas

```
$('canvas').drawText({
  fillStyle: '#36c',
  fontStyle: 'bold',
  fontSize: '20pt',
  fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, sans-serif',
  text: '一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十，一二三四五六七八九十。',
  x: 50, y: 50,
  maxWidth: 300
});
```

In the above example, "text wrap" is not working for the Chinese words. How do I solve this problem?